# CNAME for External Host

Tags: community, custom-domain

There doesn't seem to be any information if you are hosting your own server with domain for this option on custom domains for communities.

Do I need the CNAME added to DNS for `A non-Salesforce host or service serves this domain over HTTPS` just like I do for other options like Salesforce hosted: `Salesforce serves the domain over HTTPS, on Salesforce's servers, using your HTTPS certificate`? I guess the steps aren't clear because every single example uses HTTPS Certificates.

Comment: Which Custom Domain [option](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5) are you asking about? The only option with HTTP (NOT HTTPS) service does not allow an external, non-SF host

Comment: @identigral, it's mentioned in my question: A non-Salesforce host or service serves this domain over HTTPS. I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Step 1 of the instructions: _Your custom domain that points to the Salesforce internal CNAME_. They could have phrased it better such as "Point your custom domain to the Salesforce CNAME" by adding a record in your DNS.